# TokenAuthentication object has no attribute 'get_user'

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I'm trying to authenticate a user with an Authorization header containing a token generated by django-rest-knox. I also have two other authentication backends. To do this, I call the authenticate() method defined in knox.auth. However, it returns this error and fails to authenticate the user: `WrappedAttributeError at /login/
'TokenAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_user'`
It gets fixed if I define a get_user() method for a class that inherits from TokenAuthentication and use that class instead. Is there something I can fix so that I don't have to implement that or find out what middleware is triggering this function call?

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication

class GetAuthToken(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        user = TokenAuthentication().authenticate(request=request)
        if user:
            return Response(status=200)
        else:
            requestToken = request.data.get('requestToken')
            if not requestToken:
                return Response({'result': 'error'})

            user = User.objects.all().first()
            if user is None:  
                return super().post(request, format=None)
            else:
                login(request, user, backend='knox.auth.TokenAuthentication')
                return super().post(request, format=None)
        return super().post(request, format=None)
```

settings.py

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'adminutil',
    'advisory',
    'knox',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

These are the server logs:

````
[01/Oct/2019 16:33:58] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 160
Internal Server Error: /login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 493, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 410, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 220, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 78, in wrap_attributeerrors
    raise exc.with_traceback(info[2])
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 74, in wrap_attributeerrors
    yield
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 220, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 373, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py", line 123, in authenticate
    if not user or not user.is_active:
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 392, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 12, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "/home/shaily/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 189, in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'TokenAuthentication' object has no attribute 'get_user' ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-rest-knox, as the name implies, is an authentication library for Django REST Framework, not for Django itself. You've correctly added it to the REST_FRAMEWORK DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES setting, but you've also added it to the main Django AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting, where it doesn't belong. Remove it from there.